# Generic parameter in static method is calling the same class - is there a better option?

Tags: c#

I have a base class which contains a method. I want to be able to call that method from an instance of a derived class (where the method is possibly overriden) using a static method defined in the base class. Currently my code looks like this:

**Base Class**

```
public abstract class BaseClass<T> where T : class, new()
{
    protected BaseClass()
    {

    }

    protected BaseClass(string constructorParam)
    {
        Property = constructorParam;
    }

    protected readonly string Property;

    public virtual void Action(string methodParam)
    {
        //Do some stuff
    }

    public static void DoAction<U>(string constructorParam, string methodParam) where U : BaseClass<T>, new()
    {
        BaseClass<T> myObject = (BaseClass<T>) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(U), new object[] {constructorParam});
        myObject.Action(methodParam);
    }
```

}

**Derived Class**

```
public DerivedClass : Migrater<SomeClass>
{
    public DerivedClass()
    {
    }

    public DerivedClass(string constructorParam) : base(constructorParam)
    {
    }

    public override void Action(string emthodParam)
    {
        //Do some other stuff   
    }
}
```

This all works, however at the moment when I call my DoAction method it looks like this:

```
DerivedClass.DoAction<DerivedClass>(someValue, someValue);
```

Which in my opinion looks ugly and redundant and indicates that there is probably a better way. Ideally I'd like something more like this:

```
BaseClass.DoAction<DerivedClass>(someValue, someValue);
```

or even this:

```
DerivedClass.DoAction(someValue, someValue);
```

without having to define anything in the derived classes. Is this possible?

Comment: There seem to be some copy&paste errors: `U` of `DerivedClass.DoAction<U>` should be a `BaseClass<SomeClass>` (since `DerviedClass` is derived from `Migrator<SomeClass>`, which probably should be `BaseClass<SomeClass>`?) Please edit the question and clarify the naming, it looks like you wanted to make an example without your real class names but did not change all occurences.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just define `U` at the class level as well.

```
public abstract class BaseClass<T, U> 
    where T : class, new()
    where U : BaseClass<T, U>, new()
{
    public static void DoAction(string constructorParam, string methodParam)
    {
        BaseClass<T, U> myObject = (BaseClass<T, U>) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(U), new object[] {constructorParam});
        myObject.Action(methodParam);
    }
}
```

Then your definition of your derived class would be this:

```
public DerivedClass : Migrater<SomeClass, DerivedClass>
{
}
```

That would then allow you call it like this:

```
DerivedClass.DoAction(someValue, someValue);
```

Comment: `myObject = (BaseClass<T, U>)Activator.Create..`, you forgot the second generic argument, so it won't compile. And `DoAction()` does no longer need the generic parameter `U` if it's part of the class declaration.

Comment: If you need to call `DoAction` for lots of different `U` types, this could very quickly spiral out of control.

Comment: @BradleyUffner From what the OP was saying, it looks like `U` would only ever be the derived type. If that's the case, the complications would only ever be confined to the derived type definition. If there's a reason for `U` to be something else, then another method would need to be created.

Comment: Ahh, good point.  I missed the constraint on `U` due to the horizontal scrolling.